# Getting a specific value of a JavaScript object with multiple child objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am executing a query in my database, which returns a JavaScript object, containing multiple child objects. I am supposed to find a specific key value pair, but I am unsuccessful with retrieving this data.

I have tried to push the results into an empty array, like so:

```
const query = []
...
query.push(result[0].name)
query.push(result[0].token)
console.log(query)   // returns ['Walther', 'abcdef']
```

This works fine, but involves hard coding the wanted query. I'd like to perform a query in a more dynamic way, by using `token` as a variable for a search query in the entire object.

The object that is being used, has the following format:

```
{
 '0': 
   { token: 'abcdef', name: 'Walther' },
 '1':
   { token: 'ghijkl', name: 'Peter' },
 '2':
   { token: 'mnopqr', name: 'David' },
 '3':
   { token: 'stuvwx', name: 'Paul' },
  // etc.
}
```

The question is: How would I find the responding value for a specific token in this JavaScript object?

Comment: So Object.value and `filter()` it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Hi @skydeveloper, could you please mark the answer as valid if it helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all the objects that match the given token, try using the `Array.prototype.filter()` method on the object values . Like this:

```
const obj = {
  "0": { token: "abcdef", name: "Walther" },
  "1": { token: "ghijkl", name: "Peter" },
  "2": { token: "mnopqr", name: "David" },
  "3": { token: "stuvwx", name: "Paul" }
};

const getObjectsByToken = queryToken =>
  Object.values(obj).filter(({ token }) => token === queryToken);

console.log(getObjectsByToken("abcdef"));
```

If the token is unique, you can use the `Array.prototype.find()` method. Like this:

```
const getObjectByToken = queryToken =>
  Object.values(obj).find(({ token }) => token === queryToken);

console.log(getObjectByToken("abcdef"));
```

You can check out [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-mountain-379un?fontsize=14) if you want to play around with it. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet:

```js
const data = {
  '0': {
    token: 'abcdef',
    name: 'Walther'
  },
  '1': {
    token: 'ghijkl',
    name: 'Peter'
  },
  '2': {
    token: 'mnopqr',
    name: 'David'
  },
  '3': {
    token: 'stuvwx',
    name: 'Paul'
  },
}

for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(data)) {
  console.log(`key: ${key} token: ${val.token}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.values to get the objects and use find or filter

```js
var foo = {
 '0': 
   { token: 'abcdef', name: 'Walther' },
 '1':
   { token: 'ghijkl', name: 'Peter' },
 '2':
   { token: 'mnopqr', name: 'David' },
 '3':
   { token: 'stuvwx', name: 'Paul' },
  // etc.
}

// if one
const result = Object.values(foo).find(obj=>obj.token === 'mnopqr')
console.log(result)

//if multiple, use filter
const result2 = Object.values(foo).filter(obj=>obj.token === 'mnopqr')
console.log(result2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to this `Object` into an `Array` form then you can simply achieve with `Object.keys()` and `map()`

```js
const getArray = (obj) => {
  const array = Object.keys(obj).map((r) => { return obj[r]; });
  return array;
};

const object = {
  0:
    { token: 'abcdef', name: 'Walther' },
  1:
    { token: 'ghijkl', name: 'Peter' },
  2:
    { token: 'mnopqr', name: 'David' },
  3:
    { token: 'stuvwx', name: 'Paul' },
};

const result = getArray(object);
console.log(result);
```

If you want to apply `filter` based on `token` then `filter()` will help you.

```js
     const filterWithToken = (obj, token) => {
       const array = Object.keys(obj)
         .map((m) => { return obj[m]; })
         .filter((r) => { return r.token && (r.token === token); });
       return array; 
     }; 
 
const object = {
  0:
    { token: 'abcdef', name: 'Walther' },
  1:
    { token: 'ghijkl', name: 'Peter' },
  2:
    { token: 'mnopqr', name: 'David' },
  3:
    { token: 'stuvwx', name: 'Paul' },
};

const result = filterWithToken(object, 'ghijkl');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options:

```js
// You can find query in the object by key

const requiredToken = <some token>;

const query = Object.keys(obj)
  .find((key) => obj[key]token === requiredToken);

// OR you can transform your data into array

const dataArray = Object.values(obj)

const query = dataArray.find((value) => value.token === requiredToken);

// OR you can transform you data into something more convenient

const transformedData = Object.keys(obj).reduce((transformedData, key) => {
    const value = obj(key);

    transformedData[value.token] = value;

    return transformedData;
}, {});

const query = transformedData[requiredToken];
```